# Prevent multiple form submission from same user at the same time with different devices

Tags: php

I have website login system and after logging in, users can withdraw amount that is stored in database, the problem is when someone login using multiple devices and submit withdraw form at the same time he/she will recieve the amount multiple times. How to prevent users submitting at the same time ?

Comment: You can set a check for every email id

Comment: create a session id and append it to any logging in user, store that session id on the user row. Then when the user login in using another device, the script will check if the session id is available, then will flag the user or logout the user. if not the user will continue  with there withdraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a field in the users table LOCKED with default value of zero and when its value is 1 disallow the transaction and every time a transaction takes place toggle it to 1 and back to zero when finished.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275141/proper-usage-of-php-mysqli-autocommit-and-rollback

Comment: @Lithilion  that is something else.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer your questions, I'll assume that:
1. You are using mysql database.
2. A user is allowed ONLY one withdrawal.

In your database, create a table named withdrawal.

Then, add fields like:

**id** INT PRIMARY KEY
**user_id** INT **UNIQUE**
**withdraw_amount** DECIMAL(10,2)

In this case, the user can only submit ONE record to withdrawal table since the user_id field is UNIQUE.

But, if my assumptions don't match with exactly what you require, then provide more information about what you need.