# Does mysqli_autocommit work with prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a simple question as stated above but I did not find anything on the internet.

So I use mysqli_autocommit($link,false) to roll back if soemthing has gone wrong. 
For a new function I will use prepared statements.

Is it possible to use autocommit there as well so I can roll back the first three executions when something goes wrong on the fourth?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it works for prepared statements as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, will you post it as an answer then I can accept it

Comment: Consider using the object-oriented style exclusively. It's less verbose and harder to mess up: `$link->autocommit(false)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works for prepared statements as well.

See [Proper usage of php mysqli autocommit and rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275141/proper-usage-of-php-mysqli-autocommit-and-rollback)